# Index out of bound in java

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

Why it index out of bound?

I nap a picture in ---> [PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2g5L.png)

Code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int a=0,b=0,n=0;
int[][] sum;
int q = sc.nextInt();

for(int i=0;i<q;i++){

    a = sc.nextInt();
    b = sc.nextInt();
    n = sc.nextInt();
    sum = new int[i][n];

    sum[i][0] = a +  (int)Math.pow(2,0) * b;
```

focus on this

```
    sum = new int[i][n];
    sum[i][0] = a +  (int)Math.pow(2,0) * b;
```

Input:

```
1
5 3 5
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
at Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

Comment: Please check this post to understand more about `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException `
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it

Comment: Please don't post code as image. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question why.

Comment: Here: `sum = new int[i][n];`, when `i = 0` in your first loop iteration, you create an array of size 0. You then try to access the array of size 0 at index 0 here `sum[i][0] = a + (int)Math.pow(2,0) * b;`, which is why you get the exception. See the linked duplicate.

Comment: @user16320675 My edit just displayed the image.

Comment: @NagarajuChitimilla Okay i will read rule immediately , Thanks for edit my post ;_; to be good for read.

Comment: @user16320675 Okay,Thanks you very muchhhhhh.

Comment: @Reporter Okay , I ' m sorry about my picture.

Answer (score 0):

For your first iteration, `i = 0` and you initialized an int array (`int[0][5]`) which is an empty array. size is 0, 5.

And at the same time you are accessing an element at the position 0. In order to get an element at position 0 then the size of the array should be > 0.

Comment: Okay, I got it .
Thanks a lot for answer my first post ;_;